# Functions: Where can/must they be declared?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I have two basic questions which I can't find in the reference document.

Can the def() be located anywhere in a script, even in the middle of some other statements?

Must the physical location of the definition be before any statements or expressions where the function is called?

Comment: It  can be located inside other functions, block statements. However doing the latter or putting it anywhere in the script is not such a good idea. Make your code looks messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a function definition anywhere. What counts is the visibility of the name.

A `def functionname():` compound statement includes an implicit `functionname = functionobject(function code)` assignment; the name `functionname` is bound to a new function object.

Whenever you want to *use* `functionname` (call it, or otherwise refer to it), the name must be *visible*. That means you can define functions in any order, as long as they are reachable *when called*.

For example:

```
def spam():
    baz()

def foo():
    def bar():
        print "Hello world!"
    return bar

baz = foo()
spam()
```

works, because `spam()` is not called until the end. It uses the name `baz`, which is a global, and `baz` is bound to the result of `foo()`, after `spam()` was defined but before `spam()` was called.

In `foo` we defined a function `bar()`, and *returned* it. `bar` is a local variable inside of `foo`, not visible outside of that function, but because we returned the function object, we can assign it to a global name.

In other words, functions follow the same rules as regular variables in Python; mostly, you define them as globals, but you can create them inside functions too.